# How to define a MVC shared EditorTemplate in an external assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razorgenerator

I'm trying to reuse shared templates in my MVC applications. For this, I use the Razor Generator VS Extension and I set RazorGenerator as the Custom Tool for my *.cshtml files. In my solution, I've created another MVC project (as described on http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/) and therein, under Views/Shared/EditorTemplates I've defined a String.cshtml template.

In my actual MVC app, I've added a reference to this project and in a view I try to do the following:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(d => d.FeedName)
```

(FeedName being of type string). However, the String.cshtml does not get picked up.

I've tried to set the Custom Tool Namespace of String.cshtml to use the same namespace like the actual app just to see if that would help, but it didn't.

So, how can I tell the engine to pick up the editor template from another assembly?

Comment: Any luck on this?

Comment: Not that I remember ;) I hope that the new Tag Helpers will make our life simpler supporting modular architecture.